# Connecting to Access database with PHP

Tags: php, ms-access

I have a simple access database I am trying to connect to using PHP. If I use this connection string:

```
$conn = new COM('ADODB.Connection') or exit('Cannot start ADO.');
$rs = new COM("ADODB.RecordSet") or exit('Cannot start Recordset.');
$connstring = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=D:\\Intranet\\is3\\new_site\\backend\\database\\blog.mdb";
$conn->Open($connstring) or exit('Cannot open with driver.');
```

If I run this, it dispalys the "Cannot open with driver" message. However, if I try using this:

```
$conn = new COM('ADODB.Connection') or exit('Cannot start ADO.');
$rs = new COM("ADODB.RecordSet") or exit('Cannot start Recordset.');
$connstring = "DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=D:\\Intranet\\is3\\new_site\\backend\\database\\blog.mdb";
$conn->Open($connstring) or exit('Cannot open with driver.');
```

it doesn't display any message, and appears to just stop at the $conn->open line (I have other code after this to display information that doesn't run). I am not getting any error message or anything. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have `display_errors = On` in your `php.ini` file?

Answer (score 0):

First you need  uncomment the line

**extension=php_pdo_odbc.dll (php.ini)**

Then try this way of connection :

```
$dbName = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "D:\\Intranet\\is3\\new_site\\backend\\database\\blog.mdb";

if (!file_exists($dbName)) {
    die("Could not find database file.");
}

$db = new PDO("odbc:DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}; DBQ=$dbName; Uid=; Pwd=;");
```

Comment: Umm, this question is not about using PDO.

Answer (score 0):

```
$strConn = new COM("ADODB.Connection") or die("Cannot start ADO");
$strConn->Open("DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};
DBQ=" .realpath("db.mdb"));
```